# How to partition a MySQL table with an auto_increment primary key

Tags: mysql, partitioning

This is my table

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 | Cell 3 | Cell 4 |

Where Column A is the primary key and Column D is a TINYINT column. Column D contains values from 0 to 3 only. (0,1,2,3)
I want to partition this table based on column D.

I tried this code to partition the table.

`ALTER TABLE to_be_partitioned PARTITION BY HASH(Column D) PARTITIONS 4;`

> It says A PRIMARY KEY must include all columns in the table's partitioning function

How can I partition this table based on Column D values please???

I tried using KEY partition type and it also gives an error.

I'm expecting something like this.

P0 contains all records with column D value of 0

P1 contains all records with column D value of 1

P2 contains all records with column D value of 2

P3 contains all records with column D value of 3

Comment: The only solution is to remove primary key from the table. Then you may partition your table (the partitioning by LIST is more reasonable then one by hash). The uniqueness of the column A should be provided by trigger logic. For example, by using another table for AI value generation.

Comment: Thanks @Akina. Maintaining a separate table for AI values is new to me. Anyway that sounds good.

Comment: Suggested title: How to partition a MySQL table with an auto_increment primary key

Comment: What do you hope to gain by partitioning?  I ask because most partition techniques do not provide _any_ benefit, especially "by `id`" and "by hash".

Comment: I insert payments in to the table and there are four payment types. As the table could grow bigger in time, I thought of partitioning so I would be able to perform fast queries based on payment types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### DEMO

Partitioning with PK provided by additional table and a trigger.

The table which must be partitioned - no PK.

```
CREATE TABLE main (
  colA INT NOT NULL,  -- should be AI PK
  colB INT,
  colC TINYINT CHECK (colC BETWEEN 0 AND 3)
)
  PARTITION BY LIST (colC) (
  PARTITION zero VALUES IN (0),
  PARTITION one VALUES IN (1),
  PARTITION two VALUES IN (2),
  PARTITION three VALUES IN (3)
);
```

Additional table which will be used for AI PK generation.

```
CREATE TABLE main_ai_pk (
  colA INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
);
```

Trigger which will generate AI PK. If explicit value for `colA` is provided then it will be overrided.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_bi_main_set_pk
BEFORE INSERT ON main
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO main_ai_pk VALUES (DEFAULT);        -- generate new AI value
  SET NEW.colA = LAST_INSERT_ID();                -- assign it to "PK" in main table
  DELETE FROM main_ai_pk WHERE colA < NEW.colA;   -- clear excess rows
END
```

Some inserts. In 2nd INSERT the value for `colA` which is provided explicitly is overrided.

```
INSERT INTO main (colB, colC) VALUES (11,1), (22,2), (111,1);
INSERT INTO main VALUES (NULL,33,3), (3333,333,3);
```

Look at final data state.

```
SELECT * FROM main ORDER BY colA;
SELECT * FROM main_ai_pk;
SELECT PARTITION_NAME, TABLE_ROWS
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS
  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE() AND TABLE_NAME = 'main'
  ORDER BY PARTITION_ORDINAL_POSITION;
```

| colA | colB | colC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 1 |
| 2 | 22 | 2 |
| 3 | 111 | 1 |
| 4 | 33 | 3 |
| 5 | 333 | 3 |

| colA |
| --- |
| 5 |

| PARTITION_NAME | TABLE_ROWS |
| --- | --- |
| zero | 0 |
| one | 2 |
| two | 1 |
| three | 2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/w72YCxmi)

Comment: Thank you good sir. Amazing explanation.

Answer (score 3):

1. As Akina suggested, partitioning by LIST makes for sense for this case.
2. A PRIMARY KEY must include all columns in the table's partitioning function. Your primary key needs to be either (Column A, Column D) or (Column D, Column A), or you'll get `SQL Error [1503] [HY000]`.

```
create table to_be_partitioned (
    col_a   int,
    col_b   int,
    col_c   int,
    col_d   int,
    primary key (col_a, col_d))
partition by list (col_d) (
    partition p0 values in (0),
    partition p1 values in (1),
    partition p2 values in (2),
    partition p3 values in (3)
);
```

or

```
create table to_be_partitioned (
    col_a   int,
    col_b   int,
    col_c   int,
    col_d   int,
    primary key (col_d, col_a))
partition by list (col_d) (
    partition p0 values in (0),
    partition p1 values in (1),
    partition p2 values in (2),
    partition p3 values in (3)
);
```

EDIT:

1. If `col_a` is an auto_increment column, `col_a` alone is already unique. Thus (`col_a`, `col_d`) is also unique.
2. If the purpose of partitioning is to evenly distribute data. The DDL below may works for you:

```
-- answer per comment
create table to_be_partitioned (
    col_a   int auto_increment,
    col_b   int,
    col_c   int,
    col_d   int,
    primary key (col_a, col_d))
partition by list (col_d) (
    partition p0 values in (0),
    partition p1 values in (1),
    partition p2 values in (2),
    partition p3 values in (3)
);

insert into to_be_partitioned (col_b, col_c, col_d) values (1, 1, last_insert_id() mod 4);
insert into to_be_partitioned (col_b, col_c, col_d) values (2, 1, last_insert_id() mod 4);
insert into to_be_partitioned (col_b, col_c, col_d) values (3, 1, last_insert_id() mod 4);
insert into to_be_partitioned (col_b, col_c, col_d) values (4, 1, last_insert_id() mod 4);
insert into to_be_partitioned (col_b, col_c, col_d) values (5, 1, last_insert_id() mod 4);
insert into to_be_partitioned (col_b, col_c, col_d) values (6, 1, last_insert_id() mod 4);
insert into to_be_partitioned (col_b, col_c, col_d) values (7, 1, last_insert_id() mod 4);
```

```
select * from to_be_partitioned order by col_a;

col_a|col_b|col_c|col_d|
-----+-----+-----+-----+
    1|    1|    1|    1|
    2|    2|    1|    1|
    3|    3|    1|    2|
    4|    4|    1|    3|
    5|    5|    1|    0|
    6|    6|    1|    1|
    7|    7|    1|    2|

-- from a partition p2
select * from to_be_partitioned partition(p2);

col_a|col_b|col_c|col_d|
-----+-----+-----+-----+
    3|    3|    1|    2|
    7|    7|    1|    2|
```

Comment: Thanks JHH. Col_A is AI field. How can I maintain uniqueness if I add two columns like primary key (col_d,col_a). What Akina suggested is new to me. Maintaining a separate table for key values.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You enlightened me. Saved my work. I don't have to worry as col_a is already an AI field.

Answer (score 1):

The other Answers explain *how* to do Partitioning.  I will explain *why you don't need* Partitioning.

Let's see the `SELECT` that would benefit.  It sounds like it has

```
WHERE colc = ...
  AND cola = ...
```

In that case, a non-partitioned table with

```
INDEX(colc, cola)
```

is likely to be as fast *or faster* than *any* flavor of `PARTITION BY ...(colc)`.

Comment: Hi Rick. Thank you. Table is about 4GB in size. Do you think this way is faster than partitioning. I thought it would be faster if I partitioned the table into 4 based on entry type so I could use only one fourth (1/4) of the table at a time for querying.

Comment: With a suitable index, you are reading exactly the same amount of data.  This will dominate the time taken.  So the performance difference comes from the structure differences.